# Class Illuminate\Support\Composer not found after composer update (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I have a project in Laravel 5.1 and I updated composer, immediately after it was updated I got the following error:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled

  [ReflectionException]                             
  Class Illuminate\Support\Composer does not exist  

Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

What I've found on the Internet all information available is for Laravel 5.2, mine is Laravel 5.1.

I must mention that all `php artisan` commands do not work, returns same error.

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Run `composer update --no-scripts` to remove package that doesn't exists

Comment: that did it. Thank you!

Comment: I have to provide it as answer to help other. Please accept my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run `composer update --no-scripts` to remove packages that doesn't exists.

Comment: Do you know why is this occurring in Laravel 5.1? Thank you